# Print lines that have more than 2 items

Tags: bash, shell, unix

what is the `unix` command that prints the lines of a file that have more than 2 items
For example a file that has in each line has items separated by tabs.

```
dog elephant 
fox dog monkey
bear bird 
fish puppy
```

In the above file the output will be `fox dog monkey`.

In python it would be:

```
if len(line)> 2: 
print line
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With awk

```
awk 'NF>2' file
```

.....................

Comment: Add `-F '\t'` to only consider tab separated fields.

Answer (score 1):

Another awk option:

```
awk '{ if ($3) print $0}' file
```

Comment: Nice one. And you can make it even shorter like this: `awk '$3' file`

Comment: Wow that is concise! I am new to awk so thank you for pointing that out. You should really post that as an answer. It's the best one so far

Comment: Of course, this will only work if `$3` is neither zero nor the empty string.

Comment: Agree with Kevin. Safer to check number of fields.